# What did the Jedi do with regards to the Sith in the decade before the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, sith

After the events of Episode I, the Jedi are now aware that the Sith have survived. In the decade after, the Jedi were not yet fully preoccupied by the galaxy-wide Clone Wars, and life was largely as it has always been for centuries.

During that time, did the Jedi do anything to investigate the newly-discovered Sith and/or attempt to find and defeat them?

Please divide your answers between canon and Legends.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that they put together a really well-designed to-do list on the subject.

Comment: I think the real question is: "During that time, did the Jedi do anything about *anything?*" I once wrote a parody, set right after Episode 1, in which I described a typical session of the Jedi Council. The basic plot was that someone raises a very logical subject of concern, and the consensus is that the Jedi shouldn't do anything in particular. Move on to the next topic on the agenda . . . same result . . . and repeat! (As you might guess, I was **not** impressed by how the Old Republic Jedi Council came across when we got our first good look at 'em in "The Phantom Menace.")

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question, presently there is a huge gap in Canon between Episode I and Episode II. It looks like not only Jedi were busy doing nothing, but Palpatine wasted almost two of his terms. Quote from novel Tarkin :

> “The Supreme Chancellor is not required to bribe me into remaining
>   loyal to him.”
>
> “As a complement to previous bribes, you mean. In allowing your
>   illegal actions in the Seswenna to go completely unchecked since you
>   abetted in the undermining of Finis Valorum.” Dooku snorted in scorn.
>   “A strong leader would never have allowed galactic events to reach a
>   point of crisis. He is weak and inadequate.”
>
> Tarkin shook his head negatively. “He is hemmed in by a corrupt and
>   incompetent Senate. Otherwise the Republic would have already raised a
>   military to oppose you.”
>
> “Ah, but the **end of his second term is upon him**, Governor, with no one
>   of any merit to succeed him. Unless, of course … some crisis results
>   in his term being extended.”

Of course, something was happening behind the scenes, but there were no apparent results. Jedi were none the wiser at the beginning of Episode 2, then they were at the end of Episode 1. They even didn't suspect Dooku who left the Order. We could only hope that Disney or who ever owns SW franchise would find interest to cover Anakin's Padawan years with Obi-Wan, so we could get some information what happened in that period .

Comment: The Jedi dealt with the  Separatists.